# Combine my two queries into one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to combine these two queries in one query:

```
SELECT s.student_id, s.name,
COUNT(a.student_id) as count
FROM students s
LEFT JOIN absences a ON a.student_id = s.student_id
GROUP BY a.student_id, s.name
ORDER BY count DESC


SELECT s.unitid, s.unitname,
COUNT(a.unitid) as count
FROM subjects s
LEFT JOIN absences a ON a.unitid = s.unitid
GROUP BY s.unitid, s.unitname
ORDER BY count DESC");
```

This is what the first query shows:

```
Student ID  Student Name    ABSENCES
5       donald duck          21
3       safedin smith    13
6       ace ventura         11
```

This is what i want it to show when i combine them

```
Student ID Unit ID  Unit Name   Student Name           ABSENCES
5       1       history     donald duck              21
3       2       maths       safedin smith               13
6       3       Crap        ace  ventura               11
```

So as a conclusion the first query counts the total absences of a student, I want to make it count the absences of a student for each unit:

my absences table has the following columns:

```
absence_id Ascending
student_id
date
subject
unitid
```

my subjects table has the following columns(which means this is the table with the units):

```
unitid
unitname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited query.

```
SELECT s.student_id, sub.unitid, sub.unitname, s.name,
COUNT(a.student_id) as count
FROM students s
LEFT JOIN absences a ON a.student_id = s.student_id 
LEFT JOIN subjects sub ON a.unitid = sub.unitid
GROUP BY s.student_id, sub.unitid, sub.unitname, s.name
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Comment: im glad you understood my question however your code is not working , im getting error . I mean the unitname is in subjects table and u didnt mention that

Comment: Sorry, I misread your queries. Edited my query. Please check if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Glad to help...by the way it's not a sir...it's a ma'am :) Could you please accept my answer?